# Understanding the Taylor expansion of the magnitude of a vector

Tags: vectors, taylor-expansion

I am working on some problems where I encountered the need to find the Taylor expansion of the magnitude cubed of a vector. I have looked at the answer but I cannot understand how the result was obtained. I can place the equation here and I will really appreciate if anyone can show me the explicit working to achieve the result. I have not been able to find any Taylor expansions of the magnitude of a vector anywhere on the internet
$$\frac{1}{\left|\underline{r} \pm \frac{1}{2} \underline{a}\right|^{3}} \approx \frac{1}{r^{3}}\left(1 \mp \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{\underline{a}\cdot\underline{r}}{r^{2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\vec x\pm \vec y|^2= x^2+y^2\pm 2\vec x\cdot \vec y$, $$\frac{1}{|\vec r+\frac 12 \vec a|^3} = \left(r^2 + \frac 14 a^2 \pm \vec r\cdot \vec a\right)^{-3/2} \\ = r^{-3}  \left(1+\frac{a^2}{4r^2} \pm \frac{\vec r\cdot \vec a}{r^2} \right)^{-3/2} $$
Presumably $a$ is so small to make $\frac{a^2}{4r^2} \approx 0$, in which case using $(1+x)^n \approx 1+nx$ gives $$r^{-3}\left(1\mp \frac 32 \cdot \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec r}{r^2} \right)$$